# "Pause On Caught Exceptions" filter

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to catch an error with name `FooError` thrown (and caught) in a JavaScript file. However, there are also hundreds of errors with name `BarError` thrown and caught.

When I enable "Pause On Caught Exceptions", I have to step through all the `BarError` errors before finally getting to my `FooError`.

Is there a way I can filter the exceptions on which Chrome pauses so that I don't have to manually skip all the `BarError` errors?

Comment: you could probably catch them all yourself and store them in an array then search that array

Answer (score 4):

Closest thing that I know of is blackboxing:
https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/blackboxing